# How to combine 2 sheets with expanding columns?

Tags: google-sheets, worksheet-function

I'm trying to combine 2-6 data sets that has been randomized using query so that I can sort them for analysis.

[Here is a sample of the data with the desired result](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1K769Ylj4QoNnXqr61aEZKrVz1RIE5VFRpJhKQfDYG5w/edit?usp=sharing)

I tried using {A:A;B:B} but it only combines rows.

I having a hard time generating new columns or separating new data that is still coming in.

In the sample data in the link above, user 1,2,3 ends up in the same columns with user 4,5,6 when each user should be their own columns.

The columns for Epic and Story are unique indentifiers for the questions. Epic for a group of questions while Story is an ID for a single question. I was going to use them to group up the questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this on your example sheet :

```
={B2:J10;
  {B14:D21,H14:J21,E14:G21}
 }
```

If you have multiple sheet, try something like this

```
= { sheet!1 data +     
     { sheet2! > first three identifiers  + empty columns + sheet2!data }
}
```

then you can combine data, in your example sheet :

```
=sum(
FILTER(O$13:O$28,
$N$32:$N$47=$N13,
$M$32:$M$47=$M32,
$L$32:$L$47=$L32)
)
```

General solution is :

```
= sum ( 
filter ( data , 
        filter 1 > question 
        filter 2 > story 
        filter 3 > epic 
    )
```